# Error - 403.14 IIS on hosting server, but locally app works

Tags: .net, iis

When I press IIS express in Microsoft Visual Studio my app (consisting of .NET 2.2.0 and Angular) runs perfectly. However after publishing the project to my webhosting server (which supports IIS 8) I get the error 403.14 when going to the domain name.

I've tried adding the following in my web.config file but this did not change anything.

```
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
```

The only thing I can imagine is that my app runs in .NET 2.2.0 and my server only supports V2.0, V4.0, V4.5 and V3.5

If that would be the case how could I downgrade / upgrade my app to one of these versions?

Comment: Do you face the "HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory." error when you access your web application? If yes, I suggest you could try to download the .net framework from this [url](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21) and install it. Besides, I suggest you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies#targeting-and-running-apps-for-older-versions) to know how to target and run apps for older versions.

Answer (score 0):

Are you publishing the project with **Precompile during publishing** option?
If so, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26606190/3885168) answer